# how to find percentage loss

Tags: logic, arithmetic

I am passing through a question in which problem is like `I sold a book for $250$ dollars, which resulted in a loss of 50 dollars. So how much loss in percentage. The formula I understand to fit on it is like

```
(actual change / original amount ) * 100%
```

so its like `(50/300) * 100%` and answer is like 16.67% . But I am not sure I am going in the right way or not , because actual amount is the `loss` not actual amount and sometime problem come when we don't know the original amount like here I assume the original amount to sum up with loss.

Comment: Is it a 50 dollar loss on a price of 250 or a 50 dollar loss on 300? Also, that sentence "I sale book on loss..." doesn't fit very well.

Comment: @imranfat after 50 dollar loss I sale it on 250 dollars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the actual loss is $50$, since the original amount is $300$ and the selling price is $250$. So actual loss is $300 - 250 = 50$.

However, the **loss** *in percentage* is precisely what you computed: $$\frac{50}{300} \times 100\% \approx 16.67\%.$$

By describing this as the percentage *lost*, we write this percent loss as a positive number.  If we had been asked to find percent *change*, then we would answer that the percent changed is $-16.67\%$, to indicate that the change was a loss.

Comment: but what if we don't know the original amount ?

Comment: If we don't know the original amount, then we cannot compute either actual change, nor percent changed. If you know what you sold it for, and know how much you gained or lost, then the original amount is: Selling price $\pm$ amount lost or gained.

Comment: For example, in this problem, since the amount lost is $50$ having sold it for $250$, then $$\text{original amount } - 50 = 250 \iff \text{original amount } = 250 + 50 = 300$$ which is what you correctly determined.